# node.js binary-tree vizualize

Tags: mysql, node.js, d3.js, binary-tree

I encountered the following problem: I store a binary tree in the mysql table
[binary-tree table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMF2d.png)

It is necessary to visualize this binary tree on WEB.
Perhaps someone has encountered a similar problem and can suggest how best to accomplish this task. In advance thanks for the answer!

After searching the libraries I came across d3. Has written an example, and like all works.

```
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yurayazupol/vbucyuzk/1/
```

But then I decided to take the data from a separate json file. But after that everything stopped working. The working version is located at the link below, the interaction with the json file is in the comments in the script.js file. Can you please tell me what is wrong? https://github.com/yurayazupol/binary-tree-d3

Comment: can you create fiddle from that files?

Comment: @bumbeishvili yes, here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/yurayazupol/vbucyuzk/1/

Comment: pls, include it in question, so other developers who will came across to this, don't have to search comments for more info

Comment: @bumbeishvili ok, i already done this. So can you help me, pls??

Answer (score 0):

You can't load json like this (using fs) in the browser. You can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to load the JSON (or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), etc). Here's an example of using fetch:

```
fetch('tree.json')$
    .then(response => response.json())$
    .then(data => {$
        root = data;$
    });$
```

You'll need to rewrite some of your other JavaScript as the code you have written so far is synchronous and loading the json is asynchronous.